# How do I add a CNAME subdomain to Azure Web App

Tags: azure, cname

I have a web app on Azure and I am trying to create a subdomain.

My normal website is
`www.example.com`

and I would like to create
`api.example.com`

Which actually points to
`www.example.com/api`

I'm using Ezoic and I have added my CNAME into the configuration portal

[image]

I have then also set these settings in the Azure portal, however this is not working for me?  Has anyone got any idea how I get this to work?

[image]

Comment: Pretty sure a CNAME can only point to a domain, and not a URL?

Comment: I am thinking perhaps I need a url rewrite instead for this? I am using an ASP.Net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use subdomain you need to map a wildcard domain with a cname. Details of the process is given in 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain#create-the-cname-record-1

Comment: Will this actually route to my sub route though, from the guide it just looks like this is a way to put a different sub domain doing to the same default route?

Comment: You will be able to create "api.example.com" which will point to "www.example.com/api". But you will need to register the main domain with "*.example.com"

Comment: Thanks, I was able to achieve what I was after using the link you provided along with a url rewrite